# How to verify network quality before running important benchmarks?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, php, benchmark

I have multiple CentOS servers around the world. They all are running a PHP script that tests the latency of some services once per minute.

The problem is that sometimes these servers have local issues and incorrectly mark the remote services as down or with huge latency.

Is there some kind of test I could run before the main benchmarks to make sure that the local server/network is not having any issues and wont impact the benchmarks?

P.S. I am not running a Pingdom like service, so I cant do verification of the results by a different server. I have to trust each server to send valid data and all data verification must be local on each server.

Comment: How do you know a host has local network issues?  Use that information to filter bad hosts.

Comment: I only know that when the server marks multiple remote services as down when I 100% know that those services are up. I cant use that information. I need a test before running the actual benchmarks.

Comment: Ping well-known anycast IPs, such as 8.8.8.8, 192.88.99.1 or 1.1.1.1 . If the values aren't good, the site can bypass the test. The advantage to this approach is that you can use one script worldwide, as opposed to finding a fast local service for every place.